# More Information about integrating a database into my C# Winforms Application?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I've used databases in asp.net but I now have a situation where I need the power/flexibility of a database but I need to ship it with my application. I need to access my tables and create new ones etc but without requiring the user to have any kind of database software installed. I.e. I want it to be self-sufficient. What are my options? Of course standard serialization could be used but I want to use an actual database technology for cases where the records are in the tens of thousands.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking at some sort of embedded / in-process database. Microsoft espouses their lite version of SQL Server. My personal recommendation is to look at SQLite. SQLite leaves you with a single DLL to run the database and one file for the actual db data.

The [System.Data.SQLite project](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) is an awesome community contribution to bridge the gap between SQLite and what .NET developers have come to expect with commerical database integration. With this project you get a driver with full ADO.NET 2.0 support, ADO.NET Entity Framework support and Visual Studio database design time integration.

Give it a look. You'll be up and running in no time and I'm sure you'll be impressed.

Comment: +1 for SQLite and the System.Data.SQLite project. They are very good!

Answer (score 2):

There is a good series of articles regarding SQLLite here:

http://www.csharphacker.com/technicalblog/index.php/2009/06/16/sqlite-for-c-part-1-am-i-allowed-to-use-it/

the remaining 6 articles are posted at the bottom of this page

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Sql Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/Default.aspx) or [Sql Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) if the database is user specific. If the database is shared between users you can still use Sql Express, but then you're stuck deploying a separate server installer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an in-process database. Look at SQLLite or MS SQLCE.